# Using PowerMock to write unit test, mocked method fails to invoke

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I recently learn to use PowerMock to write unit tests for a class called `Module` which extends class `Base`. They look like this.

```
public class Base {
    protected final static ServiceA serviceA;
    protected final static ServiceB serviceB;
    static {
        serviceA = ServiceA.getInstance();
        serviceB = ServiceB.getInstance();
    }
}

public class Module extends Base {
    public DataA methodA() {
        return serviceA.getDataA();
    }
    public DataB methodB() {
        return serviceB.getDataB();
    }
}
```

My unit tests look like this:

```
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Module.class, ServiceA.class, ServiceB.class})
public class ModuleTest {
    private Module module;
    @Mock
    private ServiceA serviceA;
    @Mock
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceA.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ServiceA.getInstance).thenReturn(serviceA);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceB.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ServiceB.getInstance).thenReturn(serviceB);

        module = new Module();
        // I spy it because it has other methods I need to mock
        module = PowerMockito.spy(module);
    }

    @Test
    public void methodATest() {
        DataA dataA = new DataA();
        PowerMockito.when(serviceA.getDataA()).thenReturn(dataA);
        DataA data = module.methodA();
        assertEquals(dataA, data);
    }
    @Test
    public void methodBTest() {
        DataB dataB = new DataB();
        PowerMockito.when(serviceB.getDataB()).thenReturn(dataB);
        DataB data = module.methodB();
        assertEquals(dataB, data);
    }
}
```

Everything looks straightforward but when I run `ModuleTest`, the `methodBTest()` doesn't pass. It seems that `PowerMockito.when(serviceB.getDataB()).thenReturn(dataB)` doesn't work and makes the real `serviceB.getDataB()` method invoked. So `assertEquals(dataB, data)` throws `org.junit.ComparisonFailure`.

If I put the `methodBTest()` before `methodATest()`, the `methodATest()` doesn't pass. Same reason.

If I put `PowerMockito.when(serviceA.getDataA()).thenReturn(dataA)` and `PowerMockito.when(serviceB.getDataB()).thenReturn(dataB)` in the setup(), everything works perfectly.

This borders me all day. Is there anyone knowing why this is happening and how to resolve it? I need the mocking statement written in the respective test methods because I may change the returned values.

Comment: I would suggest you to remove PowerMock and use something like: `public DataA methodA() {
        return methodA(ServiceA.getInstance());
    } /* for testing purposes */ protected DataA methodA(ServiceA serviceA) {
        return serviceA.getDataA();
    }

Comment: @RC. Thank you. That might be a solution but actually I was asked to try not to modify the original class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution involving (almost) no changes

```
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Module.class, ServiceA.class, ServiceB.class})
public class ModuleTest {
    private Module module;

    private static ServiceA serviceA = Mockito.mock(ServiceA.class);

    private static ServiceB serviceB = Mockito.mock(ServiceB.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void oneTimeSetup() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceA.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ServiceA.class, "getInstance").thenReturn(serviceA);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceB.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ServiceB.class, "getInstance").thenReturn(serviceB);
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        module = new Module();
        // I spy it because it has other methods I need to mock
        module = PowerMockito.spy(module);
    }

    @Test
    public void methodATest() {
        DataA dataA = new DataA();
        Mockito.when(serviceA.getDataA()).thenReturn(dataA);
        DataA data = module.methodA();
        assertEquals(dataA, data);
    }
    @Test
    public void methodBTest() {
        DataB dataB = new DataB();
        Mockito.when(serviceB.getDataB()).thenReturn(dataB);
        DataB data = module.methodB();
        assertEquals(dataB, data);
    }
}
```

What was changed (and why):

- In `Base`: `serviceA` and `serviceB` are changed to protected (`Module` can not access if private)
- used "proper" (AFAIK) syntax for `PowerMockito.when(ServiceA.class, "getInstance").thenReturn(serviceA);`
- used a `@BeforeClass` and made `serviceA` and `serviceB` static to "bypass" static initialization in `Base`

Tested with Junit 4.12, PowerMockito 1.6.2.

---

Note: it's also possible to leverage `@SuppressStaticInitializationFor` to achieve the same goal:

```
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor(value = "so46196071.Base") // suppress the static in Base (note this is my package name)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Module.class, ServiceA.class, ServiceB.class})
public class ModuleBisTest {
    private Module module;

    @Mock
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    @Mock
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        // MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); /* this is not needed => done by the runner */

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceA.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ServiceA.class, "getInstance").thenReturn(serviceA);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceB.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ServiceB.class, "getInstance").thenReturn(serviceB);

        module = new Module();
        Whitebox.setInternalState(Base.class, "serviceA", serviceA); // set serviceA in Base "by hand"
        Whitebox.setInternalState(Base.class, "serviceB", serviceB); // set serviceB in Base "by hand"
        // I spy it because it has other methods I need to mock
        module = PowerMockito.spy(module);
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried both of your solutions and they work perfectly! I decide to use the second solution. :) And yes, the two 'Service' data field is `protected` in the original `Base` class. It was my mistake.